# Out of Memory Error in Android due to reading large number of files

Tags: java, android

I am developing a P2P application in Android/Java. My android client needs to read files (pieces) from a directory, and then attach them to messages which are sent to the server. The piece size is between 256 KB to 1 MB. However I cannot know how many pieces are already present until run time (which depends on how large the original files are).

Here is the code that does the transfer,

```
for (File fl : Util.getFilesInPath(pieceTmpPath)) {

    buf = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fl);
    pieceInfo = new Piece(1,fl.getName(), "");
    int retry = 3;
    boolean transferSuccess = false;
    while (retry > 0) {
        try {
            UUID msgID = conn.sendPieceContent(pieceInfo, buf);
            if (conn.receivedACK(msgID)) {
                transferSuccess = true;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retry--;
        }
    }

    if (!transferSuccess) {
        allPiecesSent = false;
        break;
    }
    buf = null;
    pieceInfo = null;
}
```

However, the above code causes `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in my emulator. I could try to use `getMemoryClass()` and inform the user that the device is not suited for the transfer, but this problem will crop up sooner or later given large enough number of files.

I believe the issue is due to the fact that the files are read in rapid succession that makes OOM error before GC can clean up the objects. Is there any way to free the memory of an object in android ( `System.gc()` does not seem to work, and afaik is not recommended ) or is there a strategy to read the files without storing it in memory ?

Comment: `System.gc()` **requests** `gc`, it does not enforce `gc`.

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant. Perhaps I could've worded it better.

Comment: Did you try sending files as a multipart request to server?

Comment: I'm not connecting via HTTP. I'm just using a `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` for my transfers with a socket. The MessageFrames are custom, it embeds the data contained in the file and then the server extracts it.